# Prove that $n! = O(n^n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, asymptotics, exponential-function, factorial

I thought $n^n$ was greater than $n!$. How would I go about proving this?

I have this so far:

> Assume that $P$($n$) is true
>       $n!$ = O($n^n$)
>
> Assume that $P$($n+1$) is also true
>   $(n+1)! = O((n+1)^{n+1})$

Comment: Isn't obvious that $$1 \cdot 2 \cdots n < n \cdot n \cdots n$$?

Comment: One thing you need to do right now is review the definition of $f(n) =O(g(n))$.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How would assuming $P(n + 1)$ help? It looks like you're taking $P(k)$ to be the statement that $k! = O(k^k)$, but $O(\cdot)$ is a description of the behavior function; it's meaningless for a specific value.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, $n^n$ does grow faster than $n!$ -- hence $n!$ is $O(n^n)$.

However, induction doesn't make sense here. You are confused by the notation -- "big O" statements don't involve numbers n, it is a statement on functions, $f(n) = n!$ and $g(n) = n^n$.

Try writing out $n^n$ and $n!$ in terms of products. 
$n! = n * (n-1) * ... * 1$. Compare this to the product expression of $n^n$.

Comment: $f(n)=n!$, is that what you mean?

Comment: No problem ${}{}{}{}$